# django Edit records in Listview

Tags: django

I have a ListView that lists all questions from the Question model.
the ***models.py*** is:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

now I want users can edit question_text. I tried this in ***views.py***:

```
class UpdateDirectry(generic.list.ListView, generic.edit.FormMixin):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'accounts/editable_directory.html'
    form_class = forms.EditListForm

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateDirectry, self).get_context_data()
        context['object_list'] = Question.objects.filter(question_text__startswith='Who')
        return context
```

and in the ***template***:

```
<form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Q</th>
                        <th scope="col">D</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for object in object_list %}
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                            <td><input type="text" value="{{ object.question_text }}"></td>
                            <td>{{ object.pub_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

I can edit the question_text but when I click submit button nothing happens (just a white page) and no records change in the database.
How can I really edit records with the submit button?
This is what the template shows:

[image]

### Update 1: ## this is what I exactly want in view (this image is in admin with list_editable):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWVco.jpg)

How can do the exact thing in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a ModelFormSetView from [Django Extra Views](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
from extra_views import ModelFormSetView

class UpdateDirectry(ModelFormSetView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'accounts/editable_directory.html'
    form_class = forms.EditListForm
```

and in your template:

```
<form method="post">
   {{ formset }}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import UpdateView from :

```
  from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
  from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin
  from .forms import EditListForm

  class UpdateDirectry(UpdateView,  FormMixin):   
         model = Question
         template_name = 'accounts/editable_directory.html'
         form_class = EditListForm
```

Comment: UpdateView just shows 1 record. I want to edit multiple records based on queryset. When I do what you said, it says: Generic detail view UpdateDirectry must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: Then It returns a white page. No list of records shows up.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/rock-it.pl/multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django/amp/

Comment: I think that is not what I want. I want a form for **each record** of a model, not multiple models. what do you think?

Comment: There is a way to do this by first listing all the objects using list view, and clicking on one takes you tï the corresponding form

Comment: Yeah I can do that but I want to do it in place. Can I use formsets?

Comment: YES Use Formsets@Amin.B